# how to jump out of and resume at arbitrary locations in c-code without refactoring

Tags: c, embedded, micropython

**BACKGROUND**

I'm integrating [micropython](https://github.com/micropython/micropython) into my custom **cooperative** multitasking OS (no, my company won't change to pre-preemptive)

Micropython uses [garbage collection](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/wiki/Memory-Manager) and this takes much more time than my alloted time slice *even when there's nothing to collect* i.e. I called it twice in a row, timed it and still takes A LOT of time.

**OBVIOUS SOLUTION**

Yes I could refactor micropython source but then whenever there's a change . . .

**IDEAL SOLUTION**

The ideal solution would involve calling some function `void pause(&func_in_call_stack)` that would jump out, leaving the stack intact, all the way to the function that is at the top of the call stack, say `main`. And `resume` would . . . resume.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible, using C and assembly, to implement `pause`?

**UPDATE**

As I wrote this, I realize that the C-based exception handling code [`nlr_push()/nlr_pop()`](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/commit/0bfc7638baa4c5a4a2351364ab770a188dcab302) already does most of what I need.

Comment: What does code need to do between `pause()` and the later `resume`?

Comment: @chux other code would be called which relinquishes control to the RTOS. Then once the micropy thread is given time slice, `resume` would be called.

Comment: How long is your allotted time slice?

Comment: @user3386109 around 100us; gc takes 600us

Comment: Are you writing the OS [kernel] itself, or are you adapting `micropython` to run *on* an existing OS?  If the latter, then surely the OS provides system calls specifically designed for your purpose.  Use them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger let’s assume the OS either doesn’t have this functionality or it can’t be added.

Comment: @user3386109 the problem is that `longjmp` is not reversible i.e. once it’s called, you can’t call some other function to go back. `longjmp` provides me my `pause` function but I still need my `resume`

Comment: @Adrian, let's instead *not* deal in hypotheticals.  If your OS does not provide system calls such as I describe, then I don't see how it can be characterized as a "cooperative multitasking OS".  In that case, do correct your question to describe your situation more accurately.  On the other hand, if your OS *does* provide such system calls then they are the right thing to use for the purpose you describe.  It is then pointless to solicit alternatives.

Comment: @Adrian, as for `nlr_push()` / `nlr_pop()`, I suggest you study them more closely.  These micropython-specific functions appear to be focused on cleanup in the context of exception handling, and they are definitely implemented via `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`.  Therefore, the `nlr_*` functions do not provide for a resumable pause, or anything much like it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger to relinquish control, a thread must simply exit its run loop.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know it’s not resumable. I simply meant I could use them as a general guide.

Comment: @Adrian, if the OS provides no built-in support for multitasking, then it is not a multitasking OS, neither preemptive nor cooperative.  The C language and standard library offer no help for context switching in this case.  You are perhaps looking for something along the lines of `swapcontext()` and associated POSIX functions, but these have been removed POSIX.  In any case, they constitute an interface that your OS would need to provide.

Comment: @JohnBollinger when the current threads run loop exits, the next thread is executed. Isn’t that cooperative multitasking?

Comment: @Adrian, no it's not.  At least not by itself.  Multitasking requires maintaining a separate, independent execution context for each active task, and either executing them in parallel or switching among them, or both.  This is exactly what you are asking about, and I'm telling you that it is not addressed at the level of the C language.  Providing such a feature, in some form, is part of what makes multitasking an OS characteristic.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok sounds like the answer. Please set it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about implementing context switching.  As we've covered fairly exhaustively in comments, support for context switching is among the key characteristics of any multitasking system, and of a multitasking OS in particular.  Inasmuch as you posit no OS support for context switching, you are talking about implementing multitasking for a *single-tasking* OS.

That you describe the OS as providing some kind of task queue ("to relinquish control, a thread must simply exit its run loop") does not change this, though to some extent we could consider it a question of semantics.  I imagine that a typical task for such a system would operate by creating and executing a series of microtasks (the work of the "run loop"), providing a shared, mutable memory context to each.  Such a run loop could safely exit and later be reentered, to resume generating microtasks from where it left off.

Dividing tasks into microtasks at boundaries defined by affirmative application action (*i.e.* your `pause()`) would depend on capabilities beyond those provided by ISO C.  Very likely, however, it could be done with the help of some assembly, *plus* some kind of framework support.  You need at least these things:

- **A mechanism for recording a task's current execution context** -- stack, register contents, and maybe other details.  This is inherently system-specific.
- **A task-associated place to store recorded execution context**.  There are various ways in which such a thing could be established. Promising alternatives include (i) provided by the OS; (ii) provided by some kind of userland multi-tasking system running on top of the OS; (iii) built into the task by the compiler.
- **A mechanism for restoring recorded execution context** -- this, too, will be system-specific.

If the OS does not provide such features, then you could consider the (now removed) POSIX context system as a model interface for recording and restoring execution context.  (See [`makecontext()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makecontext.3.html), `swapcontext()`, [`getcontext()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcontext.3.html), and `setcontext()`.)  You would need to implement those yourself, however, and you might want to wrap them to present a simpler interface to applications.  Details will be highly dependent on hardware and underlying OS.

As an alternative, you might implement transparent multitasking support for such a system by providing compilers that emit specially instrumented code (i.e. even more specially instrumented than you otherwise need).  For example, consider compilers that emit bytecode for a VM of your own design.  The VMs in which the resulting programs run would naturally track the state of the program running within, and could yield after each sequence of a certain number of opcodes.